# Сохранить базу данных в папке с программой

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

Как изменить путь к базе данных? Я хочу чтобы она была в папке с программой

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BiblosConnString" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\Biblos; initial catalog=Biblos;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: я использую SQL Server Compact, моя строка подключения выглядит вот так: [`<add name="..." providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" connectionString="Data Source=Database.sdf" />`](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client/App.config#L65)

Comment: В таком случае ваша программа не будет работать с правами простого пользователя (не админа): простым смертным нельзя писать в системные папки (а ваша программа, по идее, должна быть установлена в Program Files). Если это в учебных целях и будет использоваться только вами, то ладно. Если софт на продажу - не делайте так.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не понял, при чем тут системные папки?

Comment: @tym32167 - Что тут непонятного? Инсталлированная программа должна быть в папке Program Files. Простому пользователю запрещено писать в эту папку. ОП хочет поместить файл БД в папку со своей программой. В результате ничего не будет работать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не понятно, причем тут вообще Program Files, если вопрос не об этом. Автор не указал ни что за тип приложения, ни как он собирается его деплоить, потому я и не понял, с чего вы взяли что он вообще системные папки использует

Comment: @tym32167 - хорошо, согласен, что есть нюансы развертывания в зависимости от типа приложения. Но, учитывая частое упоминание слова _программа_ (не сайт, ни что другое), я на 99% уверен, что речь о десктопном приложении. И в любом случае, БД (как и другие файлы данных) должна размещаться в специально отведенных местах. А сама идея располагать все рядом с программой неправильна.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну.. это честно говоря вопрос спорный. Для коммерческого ПО да - вопросов нет. Для хобби проекта так заморачиваться смысла нету - сам пилю десктоп прогу уже почти как пятый год (пользователей человек 20 наверное), и всё ещё руки не дошли БД куда от от приложения убрать :) То есть это не так важно (моем случае). Но я понял вашу мысль.